# Building libboost_locale-vc110-mt-sgd-1_53.lib with ICU

Tags: visual-studio, boost, locale, icu, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying tu build `libboost_locale-vc110-mt-sgd-1_53.lib` with the latest ICU (51.2) using this:

```
b2.exe -q -sHAVE_ICU=1 -sICU_PATH="D:\Projects\icu" toolset=msvc-11.0\
    variant=debug,release runtime-link=static link=static  --with-locale
```

But I get only:

```
D:\Projects\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib\libboost_locale-vc110-mt-1_53.lib
D:\Projects\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib\libboost_locale-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib
```

What am I missing?

```
runtime-link=static
```

Should create both `lib\libboost_locale-vc110-mt-s-1_53.lib` and `libboost_locale-vc110-mt-sgd-1_53.lib` (as far as my understanding of boost `b2` goes).

I've also tried to switching every project in *ICU solution* to `/MTd`, but somehow I've failed to compile it successfuly.

How can I "*force*" boost to build `locale` as `-sgd`?

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you find a workaround in the meantime?

Comment: @coding.mof I've used ICU directly :(